# How can a static import be null

Tags: junit4

Since it's initialized in declaration, and the import implies by itself a dependency.

We have a jUnit parent test class like...

```
public class ServerTestBase extends TestBase {

public static final Client client = new Client();
...
```

And a Suite with the static import of the client and some init code in a @ClassRule using this client:

```
import static jwstest.test.ServerTestBase.client;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({BunchOfSuites.class})
public class ScratchSuite {

@ClassRule
public static final ExternalResource testRule = new ExternalResource() {
    @Override
    protected void before() throws Throwable {

        response = client.call(someService, HttpVerbs.GET).getResponse();
```

So, again, I don't understand, **how in hell client can be null**, since it's initialized on declaration, and the static import implies a dependency.

¿Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that the field accessible in the `@ClassRule` has to be `public static`.

**Static import** is not such thing.

You can either extend `ServerTestBase`:

```
public class ScratchSuite extends ServerTestBase { ... }
```

... OR declare `public static` anew:

```
public static Client myClient = client; //from static import
```